# Why does my C++ iostream overload failed when called in more complex cin and cout?

Tags: c++, iostream

Having trouble with the overloaded IOstream in my C++ class, the code below is my header file, so there is no main(). The overloaded iostream seems to work with simple cin and cout calls, but when put into more complex ones, it throws no match for operato<< and operator>>.

```cpp
/*
Provide three constructors Complex(a, b), Complex(a), and Complex().  Complex()
creates a Complex object for number 0 and Complex(a) creates a Complex object with 0 for b.
 Also provide the getRealPart() and getImaginaryPart() functions for returning
  the real and imaginary part of the complex number, respectively.
*/
/*
Overload the operators +, -, *, /, +=, -=, *=, /=, [ ], unary + and -, prefix ++ and --,
 postfix ++ and --, <<, >>. Overload the operators +, -, *, / as nonmember functions.
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Complex{
  public:
    Complex();
    Complex(double a);
    Complex(double a, double b);
    void set_I(double input);
    void set_R(double input);
    double get_I_comp() const;  //I accessor
    double get_R_comp() const;  // double accessor
    double getRealPart();
    double getImaginaryPart();
    Complex operator+(Complex other);
    Complex operator+(double other);
    Complex operator-(Complex other);
    Complex operator-(double other);
    Complex operator*(Complex other);
    Complex operator*(double other);
    Complex operator/(Complex other);
    Complex operator/(double other);
    void operator++();
    Complex& operator++(int dummy);  
    void operator+=(Complex other);
    void operator+=(double other);
    void operator-=(Complex other);
    void operator-=(double other);
    void operator*=(double other);
    void operator*=(const Complex& other);
    void operator/=(double other);
    void operator/=(const Complex& other);
    void operator- ();
    void operator+ ();
    double& operator[](int index);
    Complex& operator<<(const int& intput);
    Complex& operator>>(const string& output);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Complex& target);
    friend istream& operator>>(const istream& input, Complex& target);

    std::string toString()   //temporary solution right now
    {
      if (this->c_I != 0){
        string ret = std::to_string(c_R);
        ret = ret + " + ";
        ret = ret + std::to_string(c_I);
        ret = ret + " i \n";
        return ret;
      }
      else{
        string ret = std::to_string(c_R);
        return ret;
      }
    }
    Complex& add(double num);
    Complex& add(Complex other);
    Complex& subtract(double num);
    Complex& subtract(Complex other);
    Complex& multiply(double num);
    Complex& multiply(Complex other);
    Complex& divide(double num);
    Complex& divide(Complex other);
    Complex& abs();
  private:
    double c_I;
    double c_R;
};
Complex::Complex() : c_I(0),c_R(0){   //works
}
Complex::Complex(double a) :c_I(0),c_R(a){  //works
}
Complex::Complex(double a, double b){   //works    // at first I have the i as a and r as b, so thats why is fliped
  this->c_I = b;
  this->c_R = a;
}
double Complex::get_I_comp() const{
  return c_I;
}
double Complex::get_R_comp() const{
  return c_R;
}
double Complex::getImaginaryPart(){
  return c_I;
}
double Complex::getRealPart(){
  return c_R;
}
void Complex::set_I(double input){
    c_I = input;
}
void Complex::set_R(double input){
  c_R = input;
}
Complex Complex::operator+(Complex other){
  Complex ret( (this->c_R + other.get_R_comp() ),(this->c_I + other.get_I_comp()));
  return (ret);
}
Complex Complex::operator+(double other){
  Complex ret(this->c_R + other,this->c_I);
  return ret;
}
Complex Complex::operator-(Complex other){
  Complex ret(this->c_R - other.get_R_comp(),this->c_I - other.get_I_comp());
  return ret;
}
Complex Complex::operator-(double other){
  Complex ret(this->c_R - other,this->c_I);
  return ret;
}
Complex Complex::operator*(double other){ 
  Complex ret(this->c_R * other ,this->c_I *other);
  return ret;
}
Complex Complex::operator*(Complex other){
  if((other.get_I_comp() != 0) && (other.get_R_comp() != 0) ){
    Complex ret = other * (this->c_R);
    Complex neu(-(other.get_I_comp()*this->c_I),other.get_R_comp()*this->c_I);
    return (ret + neu);
  }
  if((other.get_I_comp() == 0 ) && (other.get_R_comp() != 0)){
    Complex ret(this->c_R,this->c_I);
    ret = ret * other.get_R_comp();
    return ret;
  }
  else{
    Complex ret((-((this->c_I)*other.get_I_comp())),(this->c_R)*other.get_I_comp());
    return ret;
  }
}
Complex Complex::operator/(double other){
  if (other == 0) {    // zero division error handler
        throw runtime_error("Math error: Can't div by zero\n");
        return 1;
    }
  if(other != 0){
    Complex ret(this->c_R/other,this->c_I/other);
    return ret;
  }
}
//To divide a+bi by c+id we will perform the operation (ac+bd)/(c^2 + d^2) + (bc-ad)/(c^2 + d^2)i.
Complex Complex::operator/(Complex other){   
  if ((other.get_I_comp() != 0) && (other.get_R_comp() != 0)){
    double first = ((this->c_R)*other.get_R_comp() + (this->c_I)*other.get_I_comp())/(other.get_R_comp()*other.get_R_comp() + other.get_R_comp()*other.get_R_comp());
    double second = (this->c_I*other.get_R_comp() + c_R*other.get_I_comp())/(other.get_R_comp()*other.get_R_comp() + other.get_I_comp()*other.get_I_comp());
      Complex ret(first,second);
      return ret;
  }
  if((other.get_I_comp() == 0 ) && (other.get_R_comp() != 0)){
    Complex ret(this->c_R,this->c_I);
    ret = ret *(1/other.get_R_comp());
    return ret;
  }
  else{
    Complex ret(this->c_R,this->c_I);
    Complex neu(1/other.get_I_comp());
    ret = ret * neu;
    return ret;
  }
}
void Complex::operator++(){
    c_R++;
}
Complex& Complex::operator++(int dummy){
    Complex temp = *this;
    ++temp;
    c_R++;
    return temp;
}
void Complex::operator+=(double other){
  c_R += other;
}
void Complex::operator+=(Complex other){
    c_R += other.get_R_comp();
    c_I += other.get_I_comp();
}
void Complex::operator-=(double other){
  c_R +=(-1*other);
}
void Complex::operator-=(Complex other){
    c_R -= other.get_R_comp();
    c_I -= other.get_I_comp();
}
void Complex::operator*=(double other){
    Complex& reference = *this;   //pass by reference editing
    reference = reference* other;
}
void Complex::operator*=(const Complex& rhs){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference * rhs;
    }
void Complex::operator/=(double other){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference / other;
  }
void Complex::operator/=(const Complex& rhs){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference / rhs;
}
double& Complex::operator[](int index){
    if(index <= 1){
    return(index == 0 ? c_R : c_I);
  }
    else{
      throw std::out_of_range ("index outta bound");
    }
}
void Complex::operator-(){
    c_R*=(-1);
    c_I*=(-1);
}
void Complex::operator+(){
    if(c_R<0){
        c_R*=(-1);
    }
    if(c_I<0){
        c_I*=(-1);
    }
}
Complex& Complex::add(double num){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference + num;
    return reference;
}
Complex& Complex::add(Complex other){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference + other;
    return reference;
}
Complex& Complex::subtract(double num){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference - num;
    return reference;
}
Complex& Complex::subtract(Complex other){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference - other;
    return reference;
}
Complex& Complex::multiply(double num){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference*num;
    return reference;
}
Complex& Complex::multiply(Complex other){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference * other;
    return reference;
}
Complex& Complex::divide(double num){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference/num;
    return reference;
}
Complex& Complex::divide(Complex other){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    reference = reference/other;
    return reference;
}
Complex& Complex::abs(){
    Complex& reference = *this;
    +reference;
    return reference;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Complex& target){
  out << "Real : ";
  out << " " << target.getRealPart();
  out << " imaginary :";
  out <<target.getImaginaryPart();
  return out;
}

istream& operator>>(const istream& input, Complex& target) {
  string use;
  input>>use;
  stringstream convert(use);
  int x = 0;
  convert>>x;
  target.set_R(x);
  return input;
}
```

when doing calls such as

```cpp
    cout << "(" << number1 << ")" << " + " << "(" << number2 << ") = " << (number1 + number2) << endl;
```

it throws the following exception:

```
main.cpp:19:69: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘Complex’)
  cout << "(" << number1 << ")" << " + " << "(" << number2 << ") = " << (number1 + number2) << endl;
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
Complex.h:276:10: note: candidate: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Complex&) 
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Complex& target){
```

Comment: Please don't forget the ***minimal*** part of your [mcve]. And also remember to make it possible to replicate the error (which includes showing variable declarations/definitions).

Comment: A hint though: The problem is the expression `(number1 + number2)` which creates a *temporary* object (also known as an *rvalue*) as result. What does your text-books say about temporary objects, rvalues and references?

Comment: On an different note, in the future please don't tag unrelated languages. The code is not C, so you should not have added the C language tag.

Comment: understood and sorry about that, I will follow the guideline more carefully in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You have to overload the following function too!.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Complex&& target){
  out << "Real : ";
  out << " " << target.getRealPart();
  out << " imaginary :";
  out <<target.getImaginaryPart();
  return out;
}
```

Comment: `(number1 + number2)` create a temporary object which destructs after cout function. so you need to implement a function which gets `Complex&&` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Non-`const` references don't bind to temporaries.

So `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Complex& target)` can't be used in code that looks like `cout << Complex{1.0}` or `cout << (complex1 + complex2)`, because in both cases the second argument is a temporary `Complex` instance.

A possible fix is to use `const` references when you don't plan to modify the argument:

```
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Complex const& target)
```

Another solution (for small objects) is to accept it by-value:

```
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Complex target)
```